# Backpropagation with Momentum

Tags: python, algorithm, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I'm following [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/) for implementing the Backpropagation algorithm. However, I am stuck at implementing momentum for this algorithm.

Without Momentum, this is the code for weight update method:

```
def update_weights(network, row, l_rate):
    for i in range(len(network)):
        inputs = row[:-1]
        if i != 0:
            inputs = [neuron['output'] for neuron in network[i - 1]]
        for neuron in network[i]:
            for j in range(len(inputs)):
                neuron['weights'][j] += l_rate * neuron['delta'] * inputs[j]
            neuron['weights'][-1] += l_rate * neuron['delta']
```

And below is my implementation:

```
def updateWeights(network, row, l_rate, momentum=0.5):
    for i in range(len(network)):
        inputs = row[:-1]
        if i != 0:
            inputs = [neuron['output'] for neuron in network[i-1]]
        for neuron in network[i]:
            for j in range(len(inputs)):
                previous_weight = neuron['weights'][j]
                neuron['weights'][j] += l_rate * neuron['delta'] * inputs[j] + momentum * previous_weight
            previous_weight = neuron['weights'][-1]
            neuron['weights'][-1] += l_rate * neuron['delta'] + momentum * previous_weight
```

This gives me a Mathoverflow error since the weights are exponentially becoming too large over multiple epochs. I believe my `previous_weight` logic is wrong for the update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll give you a hint. You're multiplying `momentum` by the `previous_weight` in your implementation, which is another parameter of the network on the same step. This obviously blows up quickly.

What you should do instead is remember the whole update vector,
 `l_rate * neuron['delta'] * inputs[j]`, on the *previous backpropagation step* and add it up. It might look something like this:

```
velocity[j] = l_rate * neuron['delta'] * inputs[j] + momentum * velocity[j]
neuron['weights'][j] += velocity[j]
```

... where `velocity` is an array of the same length as `network`, defined with a bigger scope than `updateWeights` and initialized with zeros. See [this post](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#momentum) for details.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you want to remember the previous vector, so shouldn't your `velocity` updating looks as follows: `velocity[j] = l_rate * neuron['delta'] * inputs[j] + momentum * velocity[max(0, j-1)]`...at least that's how I have it implemented.